# Passing a local property/variable into a function/method within that class?

Tags: php, oop, class

I'm new to OOP, so this could be an extremely naive question; but whenever I attempt to pass a  class local variable into a function within that class using the `$this->var` syntax, it flags up a syntax error in my IDE (NetBeans).

I've tried encasing it in parentheses (both `{$this->var}` and `$this->{var}`) but neither seem to work.

**Here's my code:**

```
class password_class {
    public $stretch = 1;
    public $salt = 'DEFINE_SALT';
    public $algo = 'sha256';

    function create_salt() {
        $this->salt = md5(rand()).uniqid();
    }

    function hash_pass($pass, $this->algo, $this->salt, $this->stretch) {

    }
}
```

I don't actually plan on using this for password security measures; it was more of a test to see the use of class variables/functions (this will be my first time creating and calling my own class).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need `, $this->algo, $this->salt, $this->stretch`, you just use them with that syntax *within* the function.

Comment: You don't need to pass local variables to a local method, you can just use them inside your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OOP if you use instance attribute, you don't need to pass them as params. Infact, if you want to use `$this->algo` and so on you can simply do:

```
function hash_pass($pass) {
   // example statement
   $var = hash($this->algo, $this->salt . $pass);
}
```

Moreover if you need the params you can do this:

```
function hash_pass($pass, $algo = null, $salt = null, $stretch = null) {
   if ($salt === null)
      $salt = $this->salt;

   // other if like this
   // example statement
   $var = hash($algo, $salt . $pass);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I figured it was my naivety. Brilliant answer, really clarified things. I'll accept when the timer drops!

Comment: @Avicinnian Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set default method/function parameters to fields of an object.  You would have to rewrite it like:

```
function hash_pass($pass, $algo = null, $salt = null, $stretch = null) {
    $alog    = $algo == null ? $this->algo : $algo;
    $salt    = $salt == null ? $this->salt : $salt;
    $stretch = $stretch == null ? $this->stretch : $stretch;
}
```

As [@Aurelio De Rosa pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320396/passing-a-local-property-variable-into-a-function-method-within-that-class/8320420#8320420), you don't have to pass instance variables to a method; they're already there for you.